# nodejs - jsftp didn't make nothing

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to make an implementation using nodejs with jsftp libraries.
This is my piece of code:

```
function sftpOperation(bigstring, res) {
    values = bigstring.split("#"),
    connProperties = {
        desthost: values[0],
        destuser: values[1],
        destpass: values[2]
    },  
    destpath=values[3],
    sourfile=values[4],
    client = new jsftp({host:connProperties.desthost, 
                        port:22, 
                        user:connProperties.destuser, 
                        pass:connProperties.destpass,
                        debugMode: true});

    client.auth(connProperties.destuser, connProperties.destpass, function(hadErr){
        if (!hadErr){console.log("auth succesfull");}
    });

    client.put('/home/nagios/out','/home/jboss/outnew', function(hadErr){
        if (!hadErr){
            res.end("OK");
        }
        else
            res.end("KO : " + err);
    });
}
```

The callback function didn't return nothing... the if statement after callback is completely skipped.

Looking at properties for object "client", I see that Command queue properties contain one object (CommandQueue[1] with value "action jboss", where 'jboss' is the value for connProperties.destuser).

Can someone help to understand what's going wrong with this?

Comment: which callback are you talking about?

Comment: hi @jack, i'm talk about below statement:

client.auth(connProperties.destuser, connProperties.destpass, function(hadErr){
        if (!hadErr){console.log("auth succesfull");}
    });

 client.put('/home/nagios/out','/home/jboss/outnew', function(hadErr){
        if (!hadErr){
            res.end("OK");
        }
        else
            res.end("KO : " + err);
    });